# BEA Weblogic workspace configuring in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, workspace, bea

Regarding CI and CD. 
As of now the manual approach followed by developers is the developers are using bea workspace studio for their builds and these builds are sent to Ops team to deploy the ear files in the backend. Workspace studio contains .metadata wherein .plugins will be created while using the workspace. As part of the DevOps implementation we need to build that in their onpremise build server which is sun solaris. The server has weblogic but not workspace studio. Is there any alternate approach  to build in the build server apart from using workspace studio.